# add TestField in new row When Button Touhed swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

there is a table view and i create a button in Second cell . i handled Button Touch event with protocol .**i want to add a empty text field in new row at current section Exactly below of phone number text field when add button touched but i cant handle it .**

[image]

table view cell :

```
protocol InsertTableCellDelegate {
    func insertTableCellDelegate_addrowbtn(sender:InsertTableCell1)
}
class InsertTableCell1: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate : InsertTableCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var tbCreateRow: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPhoneNumber: JVFloatLabeledTextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    @IBAction func btn_Add_DidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        if let delegate = self.delegate
        {
            delegate.insertTableCellDelegate_addrowbtn(sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

table view Delegates :

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                let cell0 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell0") as! InsertTableCell0

                return cell0
            }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    //this section should handle add textfield in new row when text button touhed 
                let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell1") as! InsertTableCell1

                cell1.delegate = self
                return cell1
            }else {
                let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell2") as! InsertTableCell2
                cell2.txtEmail.text = strEditEmail
                return cell2
            }

    }

//protocol of button : 

       func insertTableCellDelegate_addrowbtn(sender: InsertTableCell1) {
            print("touched")
        }
```

Comment: update table view :  // Update Table Data
    tblname.beginUpdates()
    tblname.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
        NSIndexPath(forRow: array.count-1, inSection: 0)
        ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tblname.endUpdates()

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection have fixed number of cell. you can't achieve your solution in this way. you need to create a dynamic  dataSource fo that.

Answer (score 0):

numberOfRowsInSection have fixed number of cell. First you need to create a 
dynamic dataSource.

sample code :

```
var dataSource : [Int] = Array.init(repeating: 1, count: 3)

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

  return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return dataSource[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell0 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell0") as! InsertTableCell0

            return cell0
        }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
//this section should handle add textfield in new row when text button touhed 
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell1") as! InsertTableCell1

            cell1.delegate = self
            return cell1
        }else {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsertTableCell2") as! InsertTableCell2
            cell2.txtEmail.text = strEditEmail
            return cell2
        }

}
```

//protocol of button :

```
   func insertTableCellDelegate_addrowbtn(sender: InsertTableCell1) {
        dataSource[1] = dataSource[1] + 1
        tableView.reloadData() // or you can use beginUpdates() and endUpdates()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample of code for add new Row when click on add button in Section**

//Create outlet for table view

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentInsetTableView: UITableView!
```

//Declare these variable

```
let reuseInsetCellIdentifier = "insertCell";

let titleSection = ["Add Phone", "Add Email"]
var arrayForCellInSection = Array<Any>()
```

//Add this code in viewDidLoad()

```
currentInsetTableView.delegate = self
currentInsetTableView.dataSource = self

currentInsetTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
currentInsetTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
currentInsetTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CurrentInsertTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseInsetCellIdentifier)

arrayForCellInSection = Array.init(repeating: 1, count: titleSection.count)
```

//Implematation of UITablewView Delegate

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return titleSection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayForCellInSection[section] as! Int
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseInsetCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
            as! CurrentInsertTableViewCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let buttonX = 10
    let buttonY = 10
    let buttonWidth = 30
    let buttonHeight = 30

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let imgAdd = UIImage(named: "Add")
    button.setImage(imgAdd, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClickedForInsertRowInSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: buttonX, y: buttonY, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    button.tag = section
    headerView.addSubview(button)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect.init(x: button.frame.size.width + CGFloat((2 * buttonX)), y: CGFloat(buttonY), width: headerView.frame.width - button.frame.size.width + CGFloat((3 * buttonX)), height: headerView.frame.height - CGFloat((2 * buttonY)))
    label.text = titleSection[section]
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerView.addSubview(label)

    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
}
```

//CurrentInsertTableViewCell Desing
[image: Desing]
//Final Result: When we press two times on first section add button & one times on second section add button
[image: Result]